# Server simple search functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

and thank you for taking the time to read my post! It is very much appreciated. I am pretty new to ASP.Net and I am trying to create a simple page where I can search a table on my SQL Server database.

Here is the asp.net code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"  MasterPageFile="~/PantryAdmin.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ProductSearch.aspx.cs" Inherits="RampantryF.ProductSearch" %>


  <asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1">

    <div>



        <asp:TextBox ID="SearchBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>



        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:fall16_g8ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [PRODUCT]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>

        </asp:Content>
```

My code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace RampantryF
{
    public partial class ProductSearch : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["fall16_g8ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string find = "select * from PRODUCT where(PRODUCT_NAME like '%' + @PRODUCT_NAME + '%')";
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(find, con);
            comm.Parameters.Add("@PRODUCT_NAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = SearchBox.Text;

            con.Open();
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = comm;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "PRODUCT_NAME");

            GridView2.DataSource = ds;
            GridView2.DataBind();

            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The page loads fine but when you press the 'search' button it just refreshes the page instead of loading the data into the gridview. I am wondering what is going on and how I can fix it.

Let me know if any other information is needed. I am happy to provide it.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you check if the dataset contains any datatables? And those data tables have any values in them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

few changes done to your code, check how the like parameter assigned

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string find = "select * from PRODUCT where PRODUCT_NAME like @PRODUCT_NAME";
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(find, con);
    comm.Parameters.Add("@PRODUCT_NAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "%"+ SearchBox.Text + "%";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "PRODUCT_NAME");
    GridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    GridView2.DataBind();

}
```

Also change the AutoGenerateColumns as true in the aspx page.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Mark this as answer if it is helped you to solve your problem